# Integrating Admob ads into Unity3D Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm trying to integrate admob ads into unity3d game for 2 days now without success, i know it so silly problem but, it's like i did everything i could.

I went through this guide https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start, like a million times, i set up everything, with the test admob codes, they show very well, but when i switch to my real codes, they never show anything, and i know the trick that you have to be patient on them for a while, but it is not reasonable, i have launched my game for 2 days now, and i'm still testing, they don't show.

Please any help will be really appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Good news, if the test ads are showing then you have configured everything correctly. 
Have you tried leaving the app running for a few minutes and waiting for the ads to show? Sometimes they can take a few minutes.
If that fails, ensure that you do not have your device marked as a test device or better yet use another device to test your application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I left the the application running for 3 days now but still nothing, and what is more stranger is that my admob dashboard shows requests increases, but with no impressions at all.
If my device marked as a "test device", it could do this problem, because i have tested "test device" before, it shows the actual ads, but with a test tag on them.